# Fit 3D plot onto a shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

I want the 3D plot to be specified in terms of the coordinate system used to draw the rectangle. Right now, the 3D plot takes up way too much space and is off picture. I  want it to be contained inside the rectangle.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{155}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3, tdplot_main_coords, axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
vector/.style={-stealth,black,very thick},
vector guide/.style={dotted,black,thick},
]


\draw[thick,tdplot_main_coords] (1.5,0.5,0)-- (1.5,-0.5,0) -- (-1.5,-0.5,0)--(-1.5,0.5,0)--cycle;

\begin{axis}[hide axis, view={55}{45}]
    \addplot3[surf, colormap/hot2, samples=41, domain=0:1] {sin(300*x)*sin(300*y)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just draw the rectangle inside the `axis` environment (i.e., reverse of what you are asking). Use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` so that you can use direct coordinates like `(0,0,-1)` (otherwise, you need `(axis cs: 0,0,-1)`).

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}   %% <<--- use this

\begin{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{155}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3, tdplot_main_coords, axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
vector/.style={-stealth,black,very thick},
vector guide/.style={dotted,black,thick},
]
\begin{axis}[hide axis,view={55}{45}]
    \draw[thick] (0,0,-1) -- (0,1,-1) -- (1,1,-1)-- (1,0,-1) -- cycle;  %% <<-- draw it
    \addplot3[surf, colormap/hot2, samples=41, domain=0:1] {sin(300*x)*sin(300*y)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remove `varwidth` option from the `\documentclass` BTW.

**Edit**

You can also plot the rectangle. Choose appropriate coordinates as in

```
\addplot3[thick] coordinates{(-1,-1,-1)  (-1,1,-1)  (1,1,-1) (1,-1,-1)}--cycle;  %% <<-- plot it
```

Complete code will be:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}   %% <<--- use this

\begin{document}


\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{155}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3, tdplot_main_coords, axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
vector/.style={-stealth,black,very thick},
vector guide/.style={dotted,black,thick},
]
\begin{axis}[hide axis,view={55}{45}]
    \addplot3[thick] coordinates{(-1,-1,-1)  (-1,1,-1)  (1,1,-1) (1,-1,-1)}--cycle;  %% <<-- plot it
    \addplot3[surf, colormap/hot2, samples=41, domain=0:1] {sin(300*x)*sin(300*y)};
    %\addplot3[surf, colormap/hot2, samples=41, domain=-0.5:0.5,y domain=-1:1] {sin(300*x)*sin(300*y)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the error: `Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.12' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors'. I am going to ignore this key. \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` I am running texstudio 2.9.4

Comment: @Jack Please update your `pgfplots` or simply use `axis cs:` in front of those coordinates like `(axis cs: 0,0,-1)` in all those coordinates and remove  `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}`.

Comment: Great, very helpful! Just one more thing - is there any way I can manually shift around the plot? Lets say I just want the plot to cover the range x in [-0.5:0.5] and y in [-1:1] how can I do this? So I want the rectangle to stay fixed and visible but the functions that I plot to be able to move around (i.e. the origin of the plot) to move around within the rectangle, as well as changing the axes ranges irrespective of the shape dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. But if I make my rectangle any bigger it goes "out" of the picture and can't be seen. It seems the 3d plot controls the extent of the picture?

Comment: @Jack See the edit. You can plot the rectangle.

Comment: @Jack Not at all :-) No question can be stupid but  answers can be some times  :-)